# Comment Store in Laravel Redirecting to Home Page

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-blade

I have a comment form in a page when I submit this form it's redirecting to the home page.

**Routes**

```php
Route::get('/post/{slug}', 'API\PostController@show')->name('post.show');
Route::post('/post/{slug}', 'API\PostController@addComment')->name('post.comment');
Route::get('{path}',"HomeController@index")->where( 'path', '([A-z\d-\/_.]+)?' );
```

**Blade**

```php
<form action="{{route('post.comment',$currentPost->slug)}}" method="POST">
    <div class=" row blog-form">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="frm_grp col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
        </div>
        <div class="frm_grp col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
        </div>
        <div class="frm_grp col-md-12">
            <input type="text" name="website" placeholder="Website"/>
        </div>
        <div class="frm_grp col-md-12">
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="frm_grp col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Post Comment"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you show us the addComment function ?

Comment: Please share `addComment` where the redirect is occurring!